# asp.net mvc controllers calling inputs from one controller to antoher

Tags: asp.net-mvc

example: 
I have controller, contact where I have :

```
public ActionResult Index(string alias = "")
{      
    var list = db2.Pages.ToList();
    var PageModel = list.Where(x => x.PageModelID == 14).SingleOrDefault();

    ViewData["ContactTitle"] = PageModel.Title;
    ViewData["ContactContent"] = PageModel.Content;

    return View(ViewData);
}
```

and I want to add footer controller, so i created it, like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string alias = "")
{
    var list = db.Pages.ToList();
    var PageModel = list.Where(x => x.PageModelID == 15).SingleOrDefault();

    ViewData["FooterContent"] = PageModel.Content;

    return View(ViewData);
}
```

Now I want to add footercontroller to every other controller, in my views everything is OK, you put response.write where should it be and it works but it write information from contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public ActionResult Index(string alias = "") {

    var list = db2.Pages.ToList();
    var PageModel = list.Where(x => x.PageModelID == 14).SingleOrDefault();
    ViewData["ContactTitle"] = PageModel.Title;
    ViewData["ContactContent"] = PageModel.Content;

        var FooterModel = list.Where(x => x.PageModelID == 15).SingleOrDefault();
        ViewData["FooterContent"] = FooterModel.Content;
    return View(ViewData);
}
```

and in footer controller too,

```
       var FooterModel = list.Where(x => x.PageModelID == 15).SingleOrDefault();
        ViewData["FooterContent"] = FooterModel.Content;
```